# YouTube Music no longer shows community playlists

Tags: youtube-music

I have used YouTube Music to listen to playlists that are created by the community.

Those lists were shown in the *Discovery* tab under the *Moods and genres* section. It contained the official playlists and the community lists below them.

Now, when I choose Discovery, I can see the following lists:

- New albums
- Moods and genres
- Trending

If I choose *Moods and genres*, I can only see some officially sorted playlist, no community content.

[image]

Where can I find now the community playlists?